# Optimization using ga algorithm

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I need to do an optimization problem using ga algorithm. The number of decision variable is 3. i.e 3 x 1 matrix. but first element is always 0. keeping this as reference I want to optmize other two variables. How can I do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just use

```
lb = [0,0,0];
ub = [0,8,8];
IntCon = [0 2 3];
```

Comment: @ Rody It works fine..    IntCon=[1 2 3];